# Void pointer to get csv records

Tags: c, csv

I need to load in memory a big csv file and test how many time is spent to load all records. I used void pointer to store records and I used clock() function to get execution time. During execution I got segmentation fault. Chance are I did not allocate memory properly for some part of my struct, but I think  I did it. So I would a point of view that isn't mine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  

struct record{
    int id;
    char* field1;
    int field2;
    float field3; 
};

typedef struct genericArray{
    void** array;
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long capacity;
    int (*precedes)(void*,void*);
}GenericArray;

static void load_array(const char* file_name, GenericArray* array){
    char *read_line_p;
    char buffer[4096];
    int buf_size = 4096;
    FILE *fp;
    printf("\nLoading data from file...\n");
    fp = fopen(file_name,"r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"main: unable to open the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(fgets(buffer,buf_size,fp) != NULL){
        read_line_p = malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char)*sizeof(int)*sizeof(float));
        if(read_line_p == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"main: unable to allocate memory for the read line");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }   
        strcpy(read_line_p,buffer); //e ci copio la stringa letta nel buffer
        char *id_field_in_read_line_p = strtok(NULL, ",");
        char *field1_in_read_line_p = strtok(read_line_p,",");
        char *field2_in_read_line_p = strtok(NULL,",");  
        char *field3_in_read_line_p = strtok(NULL, ",");
        char *field1 = malloc((strlen(field1_in_read_line_p)+1)*sizeof(char));
        if(field1 == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"main: unable to allocate memory for the string field of the read record");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }  
        strcpy(field1,field1_in_read_line_p); 
        int field2 = atoi(field2_in_read_line_p); 
        float field3 = atof(field3_in_read_line_p);
        struct record *record_p = malloc(sizeof(struct record));
        if(field1 == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"main: unable to allocate memory for the read record");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }   
        record_p->field1 = field1;
        record_p->field2 = field2;
        record_p->field3 = field3;
        //ordered_array_add(array, (void*)record_p);
        free(read_line_p);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\nData loaded\n");
}

int main(){
    clock_t begin = clock();
    GenericArray* arr;
    load_array("records.csv", arr);

    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("execution time: %d\n", time_spent);
}
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: What is going on here? `read_line_p = malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char)*sizeof(int)*sizeof(float));` That calculation makes no sense at all. I think your `malloc()` calls are confused and aren't doing what they should be doing.

Comment: What also makes no sense at all: `char *id_field_in_read_line_p = strtok(NULL, ",");` is invoked *before* the primer for `strtok` has been set. I.e. `strtok` has never been called with a valid buffer pointer when that line is first encountered; that doesn't happen until the next line.

Comment: Why do you even reallocate the line? You already have it in the buffer, so why do you waste time by `malloc` plus `strcpy` it?

Comment: `if(field1 == NULL){` is kind of a strange thing to see considering you've already copied something to that pointer with `strcpy()` earlier. That ship has sailed! If the pointer *was* `NULL` you're already done for.

Comment: It also looks like you're preserving pointers to something that you then proceed to trash with a `free()`. That's undefined behaviour. Tip: Make copies using `strdup()` if you have POSIX support, or the equivalent if you don't.

Comment: It's worth noting that the utility of this "generic array" is marginal at best and should probably just be removed. Write code for the situations you have, not those you might, conceivably have in some distant future that probably won't happen. Unnecessarily generic code carries a lot of overhead, both cognitive and compute-wise.

Comment: @tadman why is `read_line_p = malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char)*sizeof(int)*sizeof(float));` wrong?

Comment: @hawk precisely for the reason he stated: that calculation *makes no sense*. And you didn't answer his question. What are you trying to do with that calculation, and why? I concur with Devious. There is zero-reason that I can see for any dynamic allocation or use of `read_line_p` whatsoever. Just parse out of `buffer` and use `strdup` or similar to build the record.

Comment: That `malloc()` call makes *zero* sense. Why would you need that many characters? You're copying `buffer` into `read_line_p`, so you need exactly `strlen(buffer)+1` characters. Why are you multiplying by a bunch of other nonsensical factors? Given a `buffer` of length 20 you allocate `(20+1)*1*4*4` (`336`!!) bytes. Why?